# golang slice updating issue

Tags: go, pointers, slice

The following code is intended to allow updating of a "shiftlog" variable depending on the user's team, and to read the contents with a subsequent call.

The first request is to 'Add' an inc, which succeeds - debug shows the inc in the shiftLog.  The next request is to 'Read' the contents of the shiftLog, but when doing this the shiftLog is empty.

```
type shiftLog []inc

var nOCLog shiftLog
var sUPLog shiftLog
var tECLog shiftLog

var activeLog shiftLog

func interactionHandler() {
    switch TeamID {
    case "NOC":
        activeLog = nOCLog
    case "SUP":
        activeLog = sUPLog
    case "TEC":
        activeLog = tECLog
    }

    switch Action {
    case Add:
        activeLog = addInc(inc, activeLog)
        log.Debug(activeLog) // activeLog shows added incident
    case Read:
        readLog(activeLog)
        log.Debug(activeLog) // activeLog (And nOC/sUP/tECLog) is empty
    }

}
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding something about go (I'm new to it) but what? the "activeLog = addInc(inc, activeLog)" line is idiomatic I believe and does seem to update the correct variable, and the scoping seems right.
Is it my variable assignment in the first switch statement that's the problem?

Comment: Show the code for `addInc`

Comment: Every time this statement is called and the case is Add, activeLog is set to be one of the others, which all have their default value (nil slice)

Comment: Please include an [MCVE] in your question. Your question is not runnable, it references many variables and types that are not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append an item to a slice, a new slice is returned. The new slice is assigned to the variable `activeLog`, but this has nothing to do with whatever slice was previously assigned to that variable. You're throwing out the prior contents and assigning new contents.

If you want to modify a variable *through* another variable, you need a pointer to that variable, not a reference to its contents:

```
nOCLog := []int{1, 2, 3}

// Bad

x := nOCLog
x = append(x, 4)

fmt.Println(x)      // 1, 2, 3, 4
fmt.Println(nOCLog) // 1, 2, 3 (no change)

// Good

y := &nOCLog
*y = append(*y, 4)

fmt.Println(*y)     // 1, 2, 3, 4
fmt.Println(nOCLog) // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/wwNz4Oh3NjW

Comment: Aha I get now. I edited the code as suggested and it works now as I wanted.  Thanks!